# Unable to set Azure Dashboard card to use "Set in Query"

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-dashboard

I have a query to check average response times over:

1. Last 24 hours
2. 24-192 hours
3. The difference between them as a percentage

```html
let requests0to24HoursAgo = requests
    | where timestamp > ago(24h)
    | summarize last0to24HoursAverageRequestDuration=avg(duration), id=1;
let requests24to192HoursAgo = requests
    | where timestamp > ago(192h)
    | where timestamp < ago(24h)
    | summarize last24to192HoursAverageRequestDuration=avg(duration), id=1;
let diff = requests0to24HoursAgo
    | join
        requests24to192HoursAgo
        on id
    | extend Diff = (last0to24HoursAverageRequestDuration - last24to192HoursAverageRequestDuration) / last24to192HoursAverageRequestDuration * 100
    | project
        ["Average response (last 0-24 hours)"]=last0to24HoursAverageRequestDuration,
        ["Average response (last 24-192 hours)"]=last24to192HoursAverageRequestDuration,
        Diff;
diff
```

This works perfectly in the Logs section in Azure, but as soon as I pin the query to a dashboard, it's unable to run it with the date range "Set in query" and returns NaN for 2 of the values.

When I click "Open Editing Pane", set it to "Set in Query" and run it, it works. When I then click "Apply", it is still broken on the dashboard.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/get-started-queries#specify-a-time-range), In log analytics the default time range of 24 hours applied to all queries.

- We have tested in our local environment, we tried overriding the time range parameter using the dashboard tile setting which didnt help the request you made looks like a feature request.
- Would suggest you to submit a [feedback  forum](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) & raise the same issue over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html)

Comment: The thing is, these exact queries used to work. We recently migrated our services to a new region and the dashboards got recreated. Since then, the exact same query has been returning NaN's - So somehow, it used to work, but now does not.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same issue when the timespan I set within the query (`| where timestamp > ago(7d)`) was ignored in the dashboard.

I've tested the way with the tile settings, like VenkateshDodda-MT mentioned:

1. Open the tile settings in the dashboard (-> *Configure tile settings*)
2. Tick *Override the dashboard time settings at the tile level.*
3. Select a greater timespan than 24h

Although there is no *Set in query* option like in the query editor, it would be enough to set a timespan of 30 days in your case.

I've also successfully tested it with your query.